# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined" on a simple post request to save a document to the collection called `books`,
My payload looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "practical view",
    "author": "DN",
    "location": "room 50"
}
```

And I am just doing `db.books.save()` in my route in express.
Since I am not passing the id, this should ideally work, but not in this case.

Below is the full error dump I am getting on my node server:

```
C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client.js:411
          throw err
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at Collection.save (C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\collection.js:393:15)
    at C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\index.js:203:65
    at apply (C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\thunky\index.js:16:28)
    at C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\thunky\index.js:20:25
    at Db.collection (C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:488:44)
    at C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\index.js:268:7  
    at apply (C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\thunky\index.js:16:28)
    at C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\thunky\index.js:20:25
    at C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\index.js:300:4
    at C:\NodeProjects\ExpressTutorial\Library\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client.js:408:11
31 Aug 00:14:30 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: post the code where it is thrown

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure to npm install body-parser, then add

> var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
>
> app.use(bodyParser());

to the top of your code. This is also assuming you are using Express.

Comment: Because you need to use body-parsing middleware to populate req.body. Otherwise you wont be able to parse the response.

Answer (score 7):

Please try this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well. Thanks!

Comment: The body-parser constructor was deprecated with Express 4. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4

Answer (score 2):

Add these two methods this worked for me:

```js
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: This is the best comment, cuz now in Express version 4.16+ they have included their own version of body-parser, so we don't need install body-parser

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is an answer for this question, another solution is to check the version of your express js in the node.json. In my own case, I switched the version from 3.x to 4.x and that was enough to get rid of this error. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Are you referring to express.json()?

Comment: package.json @hectorromerodev

Answer (score 0):

if you have an error as a result of express-jwt, replace the res.user._id with res.auth._id.